# Trying to figure out a pattern's formula for a game.

Tags: pattern-recognition

Some basic information is that the game starts with 6 inventory slots and the first additional slot (7th slot) costs 400 coins, the 8th slot costs 857, the 9th 1339, and so on.

The game is called Sol's RNG ([Link Here](https://www.roblox.com/games/15532962292/Sols-RNG)).

I am trying to figure out if there is an equation that would fit this kind of pattern. I think it's exponential but I am unsure.

I have graphed these out onto Desmos up to the 42nd term ([Link Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jecawtbapd)), but I am unsure how to proceed with the calculations. Hoping someone can help!

Cheers!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where did you get the data from? Does the game have a name? Who made it up?

Comment: Hint: it increases slightly more than linearly, so it’s probably a power law, like $A(x+B)^C$. Plug in $6$ to solve for $B$, $7$ to solve for $A$, and $8$ to solve for $C$.

Comment: I would agree it is pretty close to a power law, but not with nice numbers for the coefficients. You can check resources on how to fit a power law like https://stackoverflow.com/a/75613250/11524527

Comment: Have you tried *multiclause* functions? They're interesting in that there *needn't* be a pattern or, the pattern could be *broken*. Reminds me of how post offices charge fees. By the way $1339$, *i sentio* is *interesting number*. Like thee, *unsure* as to *quare*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula

$$
y=\left\lfloor 400(x-6)^{1.1} \right\rfloor
$$

fits the data exactly. Here's [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/osivfd8w9w). You can do the fitting in Desmos. It came close enough to allow to guess the "correct" values (when you also put the floor in there).

Comment: Hi ploosu, thank you so much for the formula, it worked like a charm!
I wanted to ask a follow-up question, I was wondering if it was possible to calculate the sum total of upgrades.

For example, how much it would cost in total if I started from the 50th upgrade and wanted to purchase 100 more?

Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know about a formula for the sum.. Even without the floor it's the generalized harmonic numbers that come up. But you should perhaps make another question about that.