# Formula for calculating the sum of the equation: $y = \lfloor 400(x-6)^{1.1} \rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I have an equation of $y = \lfloor 400(x-6)^{1.1} \rfloor$ where x is equal to or greater than 6 and increases by an increment of 1.

I want to calculate what the sum of the equations added up together might be.

For example: $\lfloor 400([x+1]-6)^{1.1} \rfloor + \lfloor 400([x+2]-6)^{1.1} \rfloor + \lfloor 400([x+3]-6)^{1.1} \rfloor + ... +\lfloor 400([x+n]-6)^{1.1} \rfloor = ?$

I wondered if there is a way to efficiently sum up such an equation in terms of n so I would not have to manually input 100 equations into my calculator.

*edit* source: [Trying to figure out a pattern's formula for a game.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880004/trying-to-figure-out-a-patterns-formula-for-a-game)

Comment: What is the source of the problem and what is the exact wording used in the problem that motivated this posting?

Comment: @user2661923 The source is clearly the answer of OP's other question on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880004/trying-to-figure-out-a-patterns-formula-for-a-game. OP you should link the source by yourself in your question.

Comment: OP have you tried typing the "sum" symbol in Desmos?

Comment: Do you have access to a spreadsheet program? If you're thinking of resorting to a calculator, (and I highly doubt there is an exact closed formula in terms of $x$), you should be able to quickly hack up a spreadsheet where you could enter $x$ in one place and have it calculate all the terms and add them up for you. (I'm assuming you don't know how to write a computer program for this, because that is the obvious thing to do first.)

Comment: @JonathanZ A spreadsheet is probably what I'm going to do then. I'm not too sure how to go about doing it, but a few Youtube videos can probably help. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck. I don't think there's any good way to share a spreadsheet (and you shouldn't trust spreadsheets you get from the Internet anyways), you'll probably use something like `=floor(400*POWER(A2-6,1.1),1)`, if that helps.